# How to find a reason when mkdir fails from PHP?

Tags: php, error-reporting, mkdir

PHP's mkdir function only returns true and false. Problem is when it returns false.

If I'm running with error reporting enabled, I see the error message on the screen. I can also see the error message in the Apache log. But I'd like to grab the text of the message and do something else with it (ex. send to myself via IM). How do I get the error text?

**Update:** Following Ayman's idea, I came to this:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr) {
    global $last_error;
    $last_error = $errstr;
}

set_error_handler('error_handler');
if (!mkdir('/somedir'))
    echo "MKDIR failed, reason: $last_error\n";
restore_error_handler();
```

However, I don't like it because it uses global variable. Any idea for a cleaner solution?

Comment: Soulmerge's answer is a better choice because it tells you about the error without replacing the handler.

Comment: Note that error handlers are stored on a stack in PHP, which means the call to restore_error_handler() will restore the previous error handler, whether it was the builtin handler or another custom handler. So there is no loss in temporarily replacing the error handler with set_error_handler().

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can [suppress the warning](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and make use of [`error_get_last()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php):

```
if (!@mkdir($dir)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
}
```

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that this is potentially fragile if another error occurs between mkdir() and error_get_last(), which may well happen when your code gets more complex (as an extreme, unrealistic example, a tick function could run and generate an error before your error_get_last() call).  This is always a risk any time you're using any sort of get-last-error function.

Comment: @FrankFarmer you are right, but unfortunately PHP doesn't give us any better option than this.

Answer (score 21):

You could use exceptions:

Setup some code like so:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

And then just do:

```
try {
   mkdir('/somedir');
} catch(ErrorException $ex) {
   echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

That should do what you want.

If you want to preserve the php error handler, then after that try catch block, just call:

```
restore_error_handler()
```

Comment: +1
I like this approach, I have not tested it but it feels solid. Also it looks more oo-friendly ;)

Comment: Also, PHP's OO libraries deal with all this stuff much better http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

Comment: @nickfox mkdir does not throw an exception, that is the reason for the custom error handler that does throw an exception. As for PHP's OO libraries, yes, they probably do this better.

Comment: This is the right answer as this also has the benefit of showing the correct line number in the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

I use something like the following:

```
if(! @mkdir('$fileLocation', 0777, $recursive = true)){
    $mkdirErrorArray = error_get_last();
    throw new Exception('cant create directory ' .$mkdirErrorArray['message'], 1);
}
```