# mkdir always returns false

Tags: php, linux

I have the following folder existing on the disc:

```
/home/vagrant/project-name/data/
```

And right now I want to create new folder inside there using `mkdir()` function:

```
$fileName = self :: getFileName($key);
$path = dirname($fileName);

if (!file_exists($path)) {
    echo $path; // "/home/vagrant/project-name/data/89"
    if (!mkdir($path, 0777)) {
        throw new IOException(sprintf('Can\'t create directory %s.', $path));
    }
}
```

The `mkdir` unfortunately returns false, and the exception is thrown. The folder does is not created.

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the `/home/vagrant/project-name/data/` dir?

Comment: I used `chmod -R 777 data` on this folder.

Comment: besides, mkdir command in terminal works

Comment: To debug your problem I suggest removing the Exception for now as it's masking the actual error. Perhaps [inspecting the error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/929490/2043204) thrown by `mkdir()` will shed some light.

Comment: Using try catch doesn't catch anything, mkdir just returns false.

Comment: `error_get_last()` also doesnt show anything

Comment: Please give more information about the type of system you are using and what you have tried so far.

Comment: and try using is_writable() on the data folder and see what it returns.

Comment: In all cases is_writable() returns false.

Comment: Are you using suPHP or suExec or something like that?

Comment: nope, I dont use any of that

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `ls -dl /home/vagrant/project-name/data` and the relevant line from the output of `mount`?