# Unable to write uploaded files to disk on Linux production server

Tags: php, linux, apache, symfony, upload

I developped image upload feature under Windows and it was working fine. Before deploying to a remote Ubuntu server, I installed an ubuntu image mimicking the production environement using VirtualBox, everything is working fine except that the image upload request is returning 500 internal server problem.

When I visited my log file:

```
Request.critical: uncaught php exception runtimeException could not create target directory to move temporary file into at ... uploadFileMover.php at line 22
```

The PHP code around that line:

```
$targetDir = $uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $relativePath;

        if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
        $ret = mkdir($targetDir, umask(), true);
            if (!$ret) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Could not create target directory to move temporary file into.");
            }
        }
```

Could you please tell me what could be reasons behind. Your help is appreciated

**Edit:**

Based on Nehal comment, I set folders permission to rwX for , to no avail. Here is what `getfacl` gives me for all folders and subfolders of `/web/` (`web`, `web/uploads`, `web/uploads/2016/`...)

```
# file :web
# user: ubuntu
# group :ubuntu
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x


# file :web/uploads
# user: ubuntu
# group :ubuntu
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: Check directory permissions. If you are using apache as the web server, see the error logs. Is the directory where the file is supposed to be created have write permissions for the www-data user?

Comment: And also verify the case in your paths (windows is case insensitive, linux not).

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani, thank you for your feedback.Please to look at my edit.Thanks

Comment: @Alsatian, thank you for your idea. I have paths with lower case characters. Am I not setting permissions correcly?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Did you check the web server error logs?

Comment: The logs I checkd are: `/var/log/apache2/access.log`, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, `var/log/apache2/symfony_access`, `var/log/apache2/symfony_error` but they didn't give me a useful information. Only the file project/app/logs/prod.log seems to give a useful infomation (which I already included in OP) @NehalJ.Wani

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani, BTW, `var/log/symfony_error` is empty file. is it normal? This is the file defined in apache config in `etc/apache2/sites-available` using `ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_error`

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/929490/1005215 and then share what the error log says. We don't want to see your custom exception, but the actual error.

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani, Thank you for the link. This is honnesly big knowledge for a beginner. I need time to understand the whole thing. I will be back with php error.

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani, I succeded to log php error in syslog (`inside /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` in line `error_log=syslog`) and now I have : php warning : mkdir() : permission denied in the same line of PHP code. It is a permission issue but I don't know what am I missing in permission setup. Everything looks correct for me. thank you

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Try this: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/the/folder/called/web`

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani, I thank you very much for all the effort. I already tested that to no avail. Currently I give up this issue because of lack of time and also because now project owner needs AWS so I need anyway to revise what I implemented using local filesystem to fit with AWS. But these notions are very important for me to learn as a newbie. I will be back to this issue one day. Again thanks