# Cannot create directory with mkdir

Tags: php

I have got the upload_files script below to work on my development server (XAMPP Apache 2.4.17 and PHP 5.6.23) but I cannot get it to work on my production server (Synology diskstation, apache 2.2.31 php 5.6.30)

It cannot create the directory SY2017_18 in the data directory (the data directory DOES exist). The data directory has the following permissions:
drwxrwxr-x    1    admin    users    234    Aug29    09:59    data

I have checked php.ini and:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = "var/services/tmp"
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
// upload_files script
if(isset($_FILES['my_file'])){    
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['my_file']['name'])));
    $extensions= array("jpg","png");

if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
    $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a Spreadsheet file.";
}

if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
}

if(empty($errors)==true){
    $folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pdo/data/SY".$thisschoolyear;
    if(!is_dir($folder)){
        if (mkdir($folder, 0755)) {
        } else echo "NO luck creating the folder $folder<br>";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927564/how-to-find-a-reason-when-mkdir-fails-from-php  , it can help you understand the reason mkdir return false.

Comment: As a quick check of permissions problems, change the directory to 777 and see if it works then.

Comment: Long, I've read quite a few posts on this problem, and invariably mkdir fails due to syntax errors.  As noted above, my code works perfectly on XAMPP, so I was always pretty sure the problem was permissions.  Unfortunately I'm a newbie at Linux, so this is all new territory for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the directory in which your code is creating $folder, has it's owner set to `Apache`.

The best buck would be to check if you are getting any permission etc notices by `ini_setting` like this (only if errors are off) on top of your script.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

This will display notices too.

Good luck!

Comment: OK, I turned display errors on and I got the error I was expecting - Permission denied. Not knowing anyything worthwhile about Linux, set to work.  First I tried to set the user to Apache as you suggested, thinking this would be a user "out of the box" but I got invalid user: aApachea.  so I created a user (sudo useradd Apache) but got the error message: useradd: command not found

Comment: I don't know what stack of commands you have used.

This may be helpful for you,

https://askubuntu.com/questions/520634/giving-ownership-of-the-directory-to-the-apache-user

Comment: Norman, the thing I don't understand is the connection between this user (Apache - who has permissions in this directory) and any user who wants to upload files. I currently have a user (admin), so why change it?

Comment: Norman, I finally got it! Synology has it's own front end for managing users. There is a group (http) which is the systems default group for web users which has read only permissions. I gave this group rwx access to the data folder and all is good. Many thanks. Now I just need to sort out this "Only variables should be passed by reference" problem that was thrown up when error messages were turned on :(

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Can you search a little on the reference issue? I am sure the problem already has zillion of answers on google. ;)