# PHP script to create directory only executing in browser and creating successfully but fails when run from command line Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-18.04

PHP script to create directory only executing in browser and creating successfully but only executes without  creating directory when run from command line Ubuntu

```
<?php
 if (!file_exists('directory1')) {
  mkdir('directory1', 0777, true);
 }
?>
```

Comment: And does it generate an error message? Did you check the php error log

Comment: No error message was generate in my error_log. 
The command runs successfully from the command line but directory is not created

Comment: is this any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927564/how-to-find-a-reason-when-mkdir-fails-from-php

Comment: Check whether the php-cli uses a different php.ini file-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli

Comment: Alright will do that

Comment: The php.ini file is the same. I am able to run a script which prints out a text from command line but the script to create a directory doesn't work